# Is there any progress, update, workaround on this reported Safari 13 issue with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, safari

Anyone knows of any update from Safari team on this issue or has found a workaround?

[Selenium tests broken by recent update of safari to version 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078868/selenium-tests-broken-by-recent-update-of-safari-to-version-13)

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub issue is still "Open", and last comment from Safari driver dev was "It is being investigated", so we can assume the issue has not been resolved:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7649

The related WebKit bug is also still open:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202589